# Access denied when adding or removing user from SharePoint user group

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, jsom, angular2

I am using SharePoint 2013 online.

We have SharePoint groups and there the group owner can successfully add or remove the users. But when accessing the user groups through JSOM in my angular app which deployed on SharePoint I get

> ErrorCode: -2147024891 ErrorMessage: "Access denied. You do not have
>   permission to perform this action or access this resource."
>   ErrorTypeName: "System.UnauthorizedAccessException"

Here's the code I used to add users to SharePoint user group:

```
addUserJSOM() {
       const loginName = `i:0#.f|membership|${this.form.value.email}`;
       var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       var siteGroups = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
       var web = clientContext.get_web();
       let spGroup = siteGroups.getByName('Team WhatIf');
       let user = web.ensureUser(loginName);
       var userCollection = spGroup.get_users();
       userCollection.addUser(user);
       clientContext.load(user);
       clientContext.load(spGroup);
       clientContext.executeQueryAsync(this.onQuerySucceeded, this.onQueryFailed);      
}
```

but the site administrator and access to adding or deleting user from user groups via JSOM.

Comment: What access do you have on the site and on the groups ?

Comment: on the group: group owner 
;site: the site owner

Comment: is it necessary to be a site admin to add or remove users from user groups via rest API or jsom?

Answer (score 1):

Goto group setting of 'Team WhatIf' and select `everyone` option for

> Who can view the membership of the group?

and then try your above code.

Comment: Did not work, same error 'Acces Denied'

Comment: is it necessary to be a site admin to add or remove users from user groups via rest API or jsom?

Comment: again goto that group settings and Who can edit the membership of the group?  select group members and try again

Comment: Still did not work

Answer (score 1):

Need to check the Group settings.

[image]

I think it will work.

Comment: Thanks, It's working.

Comment: it works in sharepoint 
but not when its done through jsom in the angular app

Comment: Sorry, I have tested in SPFx with react.

Comment: Found out the problem
this was because of the site i was using 
the sites permission was messed up that was why jsom function did not work

Comment: @PalashKantiBachar the problem was on my site, the permission of the site was messed up, that was the reason why I was getting accessed denied